# SQL Server Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that creates a statement saying "the value has been exceeded" and does not allow the person to enroll into a course when the amount of people allowed in a course surpasses the maximum occupancy. I'm stuck right now and am a little confused on how triggers are formed. This is what I have so far:

```
   Create Trigger Overflow_Occupancy
   ON CourseCatalog
   For UPDATE
   AS
   IF TotalOccupancy > MaxOccupancy
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: First write a simple `SELECT` query that will provide you the information needed to do the check.  Then starting with that query, code the trigger and look for `RAISERROR`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Create Trigger Overflow_Occupancy
ON CourseCatalog
after insert
AS

declare @TotalOccupancy integer;
declare @MaxOccupancy integer;

set @MaxOccupancy =100;
select @TotalOccupancy= count(*)  from CourseCatalog;



IF @TotalOccupancy > @MaxOccupancy
delete from CourseCatalog where  CourseCatalog_Id=@TotalOccupancy ;
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @TotalOccupancy=count(*) from inserted;` - it's non-deterministic - one arbitrary row will be picked, all others ignored. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!